# Calls through UpdatePanel cause ASP.NET validations (css) to not show up

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have an ASP.NET AJAX form with ASP.NET validations baked in. When I push the code to the production environment and use the form, the validations do not show up after an ajax call has been made (the validations are still working, but the css is not showing up - ex. * Field Required message). If I don't make any ajax calls, the validations show up just fine. I have read that UpdatePanel has a bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=103134, and I read this blog which has a workaround for it - which didn't work for me: http://weblogs.asp.net/alessandro/archive/2007/12/31/updatepanel-css-stylesheet-upon-partial-refresh-bug-in-ie.aspx

Can someone shed some light to this? Thank you.

Comment: are you sure there are no javascript errors? something might be breaking and preventing validation from executing. 

update panel is definitely buggy and i steer clear of it.. but try to figure out what js stuff is breaking. 

ensure your browser breaks on js error, and try to post more info when you find something

Comment: Thanks for the response. There are no javascript errors when this happens and the validations are executing properly, even the fancy regular expression validators. The focus even goes to the control that failed validation. In a nutshell, the validation "functionality" works perfectly... The only thing not working is that the messages are not showing up. 

Not a whole lot of extra info but hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix is to put the style in the updatepanel.

The exampel directly taken from the link http://weblogs.asp.net/alessandro/archive/2007/12/31/updatepanel-css-stylesheet-upon-partial-refresh-bug-in-ie.aspx

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="TheUpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <style type="text/css">
            div
            {
                display:block;
                overflow:auto;
            }
            .collapsed 
            {
             height:50px;         
            }
            .expanded
            {
             height:inherit;
            }
        </style>
        <asp:Panel CssClass="collapsed" runat="server" ID="pnlMain">
            1<br />2<br />3<br />4<br />5<br />6<br />
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Button ID="btnExpCol" runat="server" Text="Expand" />

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```